# MySQL > update Query is not working while PDO type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on this update query, But it's not working.. Here is query

```
UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE '%:sub_string%' THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', :sub_string) END) WHERE `field` = :value
```

I'm here trying to do is... update one record if sub string exist in field value then return field value it self.. and if sub string does not exist then append with old value. But problem is `field_name LIKE '%:sub_string%'` is not working... if i write direct `field_name LIKE '%abc%'` then it is working. I want to know that why this is not working??

whole code part is..

```
$query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE '%:sub_string%' THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', :sub_string) END) WHERE `field` = :value");
$query->bindParam(':sub_string', 'abc');
$query->bindParam(':value', 1);
$query->execute();
```

I hope you guys understand..

Comment: remove the `%%` from the query and do like `$query->bindParam(':sub_string', '%abc%');`

Comment: (named) parameters/placeholders in values should not contain quotes, for one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Wildcard Characters from the actual query and add it with your `bindParams`

```
    <?php

    $myString = "abc";
    $value = 1;

    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE :sub_string1 THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', :sub_string) END) WHERE `field` = :value");
    $query->bindParam(':sub_string1', '%'.$myString.'%');
    $query->bindParam(':sub_string', $myString);
    $query->bindParam(':value', $value);
    $query->execute();

?>
```

also remove the quotes from parameters

Update

Or might try with Question mark placeholders `?`

```
<?php

    $myString = "abc";
    $value = 1;

    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE ? THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', ?) END) WHERE `field` = ?");
    $query->bindParam(1, '%'.$myString.'%');
    $query->bindParam(2, $myString);
    $query->bindParam(3, $value);
    $query->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Yes I've done that but it is returning `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`.. sue to '%' . $mystring . '%'.. then I've tried by doing this.... `$mystring = '%' . $mystring . '%'` but it is taking as whole string... like it is finding... for `%abc%`....

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile you must remove the quotes around `':sub_string1'`

Comment: @Akintunde *"might"*? => "must". ;-)

Comment: @Akintunde hehe ;-)

Comment: @DigvijayRathod can u try the second method

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yup it is working now... Thanks buddy.. But can you tell me why this is not working '%:sub_string%' ??

Comment: @DigvijayRathod a placeholder have to represent a complete data literal only - a string or a number namely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enclose the parameters with quotes, instead, you can use as follow:

```
UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE :sub_string1 THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', :sub_string2) END) WHERE `field` = :value
```

Then

```
$query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE '%:sub_string%' THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', :sub_string) END) WHERE `field` = :value");
$query->bindParam(':sub_string1', '%abc%');
$query->bindParam(':sub_string2', 'abc');
$query->bindParam(':value', 1);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

bindParam binds to a variable name and not the constant.
Use this instead-

```
$abc = 'abc';
$one = 1;
$query->bindParam(':sub_string', $abc);
$query->bindParam(':value', $one);
```

> PDOStatement::bindParam — Binds a parameter to the specified variable name

[Relevant comment](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#76357) regarding using `%%` with like and bindParam.

[PHP Documentation- PDOStatement::bindParam](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0):

PDO's bindParam will ensure that all string data is properly quoted when sent to the SQL query

Try this:

```
<?php

    $term = "random";
    $finalTerm= "$term%";
    $value = 1;

    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_abc` SET `field_name` = (CASE WHEN `field_name` LIKE ? THEN `field_name` ELSE CONCAT(`field_name`, ' ### ', ?) END) WHERE `field` = ?");
    $query->bindParam(1, $finalTerm);
    $query->bindParam(2, $myString);
    $query->bindParam(3, $value);
    $query->execute();

?>
```